# Using Sed to extract the headers in multiple files

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I used `head -3` to extract headers from some files that I needed to show header data I did this:

```
head -3 file1 file2 file3
```

and `head -3 *` works also.

I thought `sed 3 file1 file2 file3` would work but it only gives the first file's output and not the others. I then tried `sed -n '1,2p' file1 file2 file3`. Again only the first file produced any output. I also tried with a wildcard `sed -n '1,2p' filename*` same result only the first file's output.

Everything I read seems like it should work. `sed *filesnames*`.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the question or problem?

Comment: if you want each file to have it's own addressing, use `-s` option... when using `-i`, the `-s` option is implicit... this is behavior for `GNU sed`, other implementations might differ

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `GNU sed` as question is tagged `linux`. From [GNU sed manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Command_002dLine-Options)

> -s
>   --separate By default, sed will consider the files specified on the command line as a single continuous long stream. This GNU sed
>   extension allows the user to consider them as separate files: range
>   addresses (such as ‘/abc/,/def/’) are not allowed to span several
>   files, line numbers are relative to the start of each file, $ refers
>   to the last line of each file, and files invoked from the R commands
>   are rewound at the start of each file.

Example:

```
$ cat file1
foo
bar
$ cat file2
123
456

$ sed -n '1p' file1 file2
foo
$ sed -n '3p' file1 file2
123
$ sed -sn '1p' file1 file2
foo
123
```

When using `-i`, the `-s` option is implied

```
$ sed -i '1chello' file1 file2
$ cat file1
hello
bar
$ cat file2
hello
456
```